# how can I model this in a xml schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am creating a schema for an xml coming from an external system. I have a problem modelling this type:

```
<main>
...
  <Foo TYPE="Numeric"/>
  <Bar TYPE="Numeric">12.0</Bar>
...
</main>
```

I have create a type extending double:

```
<xs:complexType name="myNumeric">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:double">
      <xs:attribute name="TYPE" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

....

<xs:element name="Foo" type="myNumeric" />
<xs:element name="Bar" type="myNumeric" />
```

However this is not good enough, when I am try to validate the schema I got an error complaining that: '' is not a valid value for 'double'.

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xs:double cannot have an empty sting as a value. If you want to mark this type as a "null" then you can use xsi:nil="true" to indicate that this is an "empty" double:

```
<Foo TYPE="Numeric" xsi:nil="true" />
```

To allow this use nillable="true" in your schema

```
<xs:element name="Foo" type="myNumeric" nillable="true" />
```

You will need to include a reference to the XML Schema instance namespace in your xml instance.

```
<MyRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ... >
...
</MyRoot>
```

Comment: thanks, this is great, however it implies that I need to modify the input xml. I am not controlling the xml generation and I would like to avoid to preprocessing it if possible.

Comment: Then I can't think of how to do this other than defer typing to a downstream process and have everything as a xs:string. Which is not a nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a specific type that is an union of 2 simple types. For example "myType" below seems to answer your question :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:my="myNamespace" targetNamespace="myNamespace">
    <xs:simpleType name="myType">
        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:double my:empty"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="empty">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```